# Как задать сортировку по цене в разной валюте mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица:

- product

  - -price
  - -currency

Пользователь вбивает цену и валюту, при выводе записей на странице, валюта пересчитывается согласно курсу на текущий момент.
Проблема заключается в том, что курс может меняться каждый день, и хранить цену для каждой валюты в таблице нету возможности, т.к записей в таблице будет много. Как в таком случае реализовать сортировку или выборку с условием по цене в определенной валюте?

Comment: Создать виртуальный столбец с приведением к одной из валют и по нем отсортировать.

Comment: @Andrey , Курс может измениться, придется каждый раз перебирать все записи, и пересчитывать этот столбец

Comment: Если это не сильно грузит сервер (или для вас это не критично) то почему бы и не пересчитывать каждый раз?!

Comment: @Andrey , ну думаю что пересчитывать каждый раз неправильно с точки зрения архитектуры. И загруженность сервера прямо пропорциональная к-ву записей, если их в пределах 1000 - это еще терпимо, а если более 300К - уже критично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Завести вторую таблицу с курсами валют. Держать в ней только актуальные данные (сегодняшний курс) для простоты. Выбирать и сортировать:

```
SELECT товары.* 
FROM товары JOIN курсы_валют 
ON товары.тип_валюты = курсы_валют.тип_валюты 
ORDER BY товары.цена * курсы_валют.курс
```

Таблица "товары"

1 сапоги 500 USD

2 штаны  300 EUR

3 кепка  100 RUB

Таблица "валюта" (От id можно оказаться, сделать PRIMARY по типу валюты)

1 USD 65

2 EUR 73

3 RUB 1

Это для вывода в рублях.
Теперь надо принять валюту от клиента

Сначала получаем выбранную валюту

```
SELECT курс FROM курсы_валют
```

Это ускорит процесс. Обозначим полученный курс $x

```
SELECT товары.*, товары.цена / $x AS вот_эта_цена
FROM товары JOIN курсы_валют 
ON товары.тип_валюты = курсы_валют.тип_валюты 
ORDER BY товары.цена * курсы_валют.курс
```

В итоговой выборке у каждого товара добавится цена в нужной валюте

Answer (score 0):

В запросе нужно приводить к суму к одной валюте через оператор ветвления:

```
SELECT ID, Cost, Currency, IF(Currency='RUR', Cost, IF(Currency='EUR', Cost*34.4, IF(Currency='USD', Cost*25.5, 'Unknown') ) ) rub_cost from table_name order bu rub_cost asc limit 10,20;
```

Comment: представил как станет выглядеть Ваш запрос при большем количестве валют, волосы начали шевелиться...

Comment: @Bald , я ничего страшного в этом не вижу. В моем случае будет примерно 5 валют. А даже если их будет пару десятков, то что в этом плохого, запрос от этого станет только длиннее, думаю mysql обработает его довольно шустро. Или у Вас есть более правильное решение?

Comment: @РоманМальцев и сделайте из этого вьюху

Comment: что мне не нравится в Вашем запросе, то что курс валют зашит в теле, да и *оператор ветвления* усложняет чтение запроса... по поводу лучше надо подумать

Comment: @Bald ,  согласен, что решение неидеальное, но у меня пока нету лучших идей. Возможно будет правильнее хранить суму для каждого курса в отдельной ячейке, и при смене курса обновлять по крону эти значения?